# Spring Boot Tomcat can't start. Initializes and is stopped

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am working on two Spring Boot projects. One runs fine, however the other one starts normal and then stops Tomcat. It then throws an exception saying tomcat embedded server could not start.

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address

Below is the output.

```
org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.bidmii.bmf.Application.main(Application.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:265) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:196) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1066) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:550) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:249) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:88) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1063) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

2021-05-31 17:20:43.512  INFO 7262 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2021-05-31 17:20:43.512  INFO 7262 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-05-31 17:20:43.522  INFO 7262 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-05-31 17:20:43.523  INFO 7262 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-05-31 17:20:43.524  INFO 7262 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried everything logical. Don't know what to do next.

Update:
So here are some of the things that I have tried.

- Deleted the .m2/repository and reinstalled dependencies.
- Checked for running instances of Tomcat.
- Checked for port availability. (also tried different post numbers)

Comment: Is the port the application tries to listen on free? Do you start both applications on the same port (8080 by default) and on the same device?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to describe specifically what you have already tried? That may save some "try this...", "I already did..." comments. (Otherwise, the ports do seem the most likely cause.)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my problem. I had an environment variable setup with the name "SERVER_ADDRESS" and it appears that was causing some issue with tomcat requesting and getting an address that was valid. I changed it to something else and that fixed it.